# What can be the cause of this error when attempting port forwarding for SSH?

Tags: linux, port-forwarding, arch-linux, isp

I've checked my IP on [whatismyipaddress](https://whatismyipaddress.com/), and then I entered it on [whois](https://whois.domaintools.com/) to verify it is public, as described [here](https://how2do.org/port-mapping-on-fastweb-how-to-open-the-fastgate-ports/).

This was superfluous already, as I've been accessing my PC from abroad via `ssh` several times, but I just wanted to check nothing had changed  after the technical support of my ISP deemed necessary a full reset of my modem for a malfunctioning of the whole LAN + telephone.

Now I was trying to reconfigure port forwarding, but hit this.

What could be the cause behind this symptom?

[image]

Comment: Do you get the same error if you select a different external port? What if you attempt to forward to a different internal port?

Comment: This question appears to be off topic. You can ask home networking questions on our sister site [su].

Comment: @larsks, changing the external port does not affect the behavior. It's the 22 internal port which triggers that error.

Comment: @MichaelHampton, why? My question is about managing my model in relation to my workstation and other computers from which I want to access the workstation. This seems to be in line with [_managing the hardware or software of servers, workstations, storage or networks_](https://serverfault.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: _in a business environment_.

Comment: Ok, @MichaelHampton, fair enough. I've flagget it myself to migrate it to SuperUser.

Answer (score 2):

It is likely that the firmware is crap and the ISP modem/device is listening in port 22 and blocking you because its stupid.

If this is the case, run SSH on a port other then 22 and forward to that. You may be able to leave SSH in port 22/and on your SSH server add an iptables rule to forward requests on another port to 22 - untested but something like

```
  iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 33 -j REDIRECT --to-port 22
```

To allow you to connect in port 33.